# Comparing user array strings to list empty users

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want a simple way to compare two arrays. One array has a list of emails and the other array is a list of emails who completed a form. I want to then return a list of people who have not completed the form. Here is the function I have, but it works pretty slow.

```
  function findMissingUsers() {
   var sheet = getSheet();    
   users = [array of all emails]; 
   completedUsers = [array of emails who completed form];

   users.forEach(function (row) {
    completedUsers.forEach(function (user) {
     if(row.Email != user.Username) {
      console.log(row);
     }
    });
   });
  }
```

Just trying to find a more efficient way of doing this.

Comment: Is the `completedUsers` array sorted or easily sortable? If so, you could try using a binary search of `completedUsers` instead of a sequential search and it should be `O(n log m)` unless I'm mistaken.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
completedUsers.filter(function(n) {
    return users.indexOf(n) != -1
});
```

from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885557/simplest-code-for-array-intersection-in-javascript/1885569#1885569).

Comment: Its an array of objects and not an array of email ids (string).

Comment: @void according to provided code both are arrays of emails.

Comment: @scareddragon I don't think. Look at this line `if(row.Email != user.Username) {`

Comment: @rphv, Moreover it does not improves the efficiency, Complexity will remain `O(n2)`

Comment: @void right, I was mistaken by those variables defs, where is written 'array of emails'.

Answer (score 0):

You can use e.g. `lodash` library and `_.difference` function. Details [here](https://lodash.com/docs#difference).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
var incompletedUsers = users.filter(function(user){
    return completedUsers.every(function(completedUser){
        return user.Email !== completedUser.Username;
    });
});
```